# How do I specify a DataGrid's ItemsSource type in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, visual-studio-2015

I'm binding a `DataGrid` to an [`ICollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) so that I can filter the ItemsSource efficiently, but `ICollectionView` is not a [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx#csharp_generics_topic2) type (as in `CollectionView<MyType>`) - it is of type `List<object>`. So in the XAML editor, VisualStudio can't determine what the type is, so I don't get any IntelliSense help binding to the properties of the object in the collection view. It still builds and runs, but I don't get the help at design time.

**Rephrasing the question:** Is there anyway to "cast" the data-binding in XAML?

I thought I could do something with `<DataGrid.DataContext>`, but I can't remember what it was and I haven't had any luck googling for it either:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionView}">
    <DataGrid.DataContext>
        <!-- Specify the type of objects in MyCollectionView somehow -
                 something like 'x:type="MyType"' -->
    </DataGrid.DataContext>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- Cannot resolve property 'Approved' in data context of type 'MyProject.MainWindow'. -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Approved}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- Cannot resolve property 'Approved' in data context of type 'object'. -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Is Approved"
                            Binding="{Binding Approved}"
                            Width="3*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICollectionView MyCollectionView { get; set; }

    public MainWindow(List<MyType> parameter)
    {
        // ...

        MyCollectionView = new CollectionView(parameter);

        // ...
    }
}

public class MyType
{
    public bool Approved { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: You made the case why it doesn't work in design time, but are you saying that the binding fails during runtime when it should work?

Comment: "ICollectionView is not a generic type - it is of type List<object>" `List<object>` is a generic collection. Can we see how `MyCollectionView` is defined, and how the collection itself is defined? Do the objects in the collection actually have a property named `Approved`? What does "recognized" mean?

Comment: @OmegaMan No, it still builds and runs. My question is just how do specify at design-time that the `ItemsSource` is actually `List<MyType>`, not `List<object>` - getting all the IntelliSense and type-checking goodness that comes along with it. I updated my question to address your comment.

Comment: @EdPlunkett `ICollectionView` is not generic in the C# sense of "Generics" (`ICollectionView` is a .NET type). By "not recognized" I mean that I get a suggestion squiggly under "Approved" and the message says `Cannot resolve property 'Approved' in the context of type 'MyProject.MainWindow'.`. I updated my question to address your comment.

Comment: Since this is a design time issue, put in your version of Visual Studio as a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought I could do something with , but I can't remember what it was and I haven't had any luck googling for it either:

I believe the setting the design time data context is that you are looking for. Please refer to the following links for more information about this.

XAML: Intellisense for Bindings And the Data Context: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/xaml-intellisense-for-bindings-and-the-data-context/
[How to see design-time data-binding in XAML editor (it works in runtime)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401885/how-to-see-design-time-data-binding-in-xaml-editor-it-works-in-runtime)

> What I'm trying to ask is if there is any way to "cast" the data-binding as a collection of MyType in XAML?

No. But you could specify a design-time DataContext as described above.

Comment: The MS MVP link had what I was looking for: `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vms:CustomerListViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"`

Answer (score 0):

> VisualStudio can't determine what the type is

Since the type is not expressed until runtime and gotten by using reflection by the code, the designer is at a disadvantage and can only extrapolate on what it knows. And all it *knows* is that it is an `object` but not the *exact* type which the developer knows.

> I don't get any IntelliSense help ... still builds and runs, but I don't get the help at design time

If that is the issue which is holding you back, I recommend that you temporarily add a list of the property type in question to the VM (or page if not MVVM) and then bind to that new property. Then the design time will **see** what it needs and you can get property info add bindings/styles with the help of visual studio.

Once all is good, replace the design time binding, as it were, to the `ICollection` you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I understand this - I know what the problem is. What I'm trying to ask is if there is any way to "cast" the data-binding as a collection of `MyType` in XAML?

Comment: @tehDorf, To my knowledge, no, there is no way to cast it in XAML.