# XAML: Simple ItemsControl Binding to TextBox does not work: how to set the source property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, itemscontrol

I have an ObservableCollection that I try to bind to a list of text boxes. The textboxes do show but the content of the text does not.

**The XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfMessages}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Message, ElementName=ListOfMessages}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

**The Code:**

*In the ViewModel:*

```
public ObservableCollection<ApplicationLog> ListOfMessages { get; set; }
```

*In the Model:*

```
public class ApplicationLog 
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this, the app shows the text boxes (for example 4 text boxes, one below the other), but the text in the text boxes (ie the `Message` property) is not shown. I think my Binding expression for the Text Box is wrong.

Context: I am new to XAML and WPF. More generally: how does one debug Binding issues similar to this one.

Thanks.

Comment: If you look in the output window while debugging, you should see the Binding error giving you a hint.

Comment: Thanks. But I have difficulty reading:
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=ListOfMessages'. BindingExpression:Path=Message; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
This tells me the binding does not work - what else can I infer?

Comment: That is telling you that the datacontext is trying to bind to ListOfMessages.Message.  The ObservableCollection does not have a property of "Message"... as you've seen in the answer.  The datacontext of any list item is the item of the collection.  Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `ElementName=ListOfMessages`. The `DataContext` for each item will be the items in the `ListOfMessages` bound to the `ItemsSource`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfMessages}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- DataContext will be ListOfMessages[0], [1], ..., [n] -->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Message}" /> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

`ElementName` is used to bypass the `DataContext` and point to a specific named item in your scoped XAML.

Comment: Thanks; that did it! What got me it that Intellisense underlined (in blue) "Message" in the XAML with tip "Cannot resolve symbol 'Message'" (in VS2017); so I did not even tried. Why does Intellisense gave me this message?

Comment: Intellisense doesn't know where `ListOfMessages` is coming from. You need to use `d:DataContext` on the root element in your xaml. Look at this post for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101696/what-do-i-need-to-further-qualify-the-datacontext-for-a-binding